# How to remove audio translations from the movie?

Tags: video, premiere, video-editor, audio-recording, audio-quality

I want to cut an existing movie and want to remove all the language track from it.

The thing is when I start to edit the movie, Premiere Pro just picks up some language, which is not suitable for me. How do I remove all the soundtracks except the one I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to cut an existing movie and want to remove all the language track from it.

ffmpeg -i  -c copy -an video_only.mp4

> How do I remove all the soundtracks except the one I need?

ffmpeg -i  -c copy -map 0:a:1 specified.mp4

Reference: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map